# Being the components of the iOS both cocoa Touch and openGL has different co-ordinate system. Why is it so

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am beginner for the cocos2d, but thought that cocos2d derived from the openGL. Actually I am having basic knowledge for UIKit also. So I wanted to know the difference in the Co-ordinate system in that. Both are meant for iOS but both are having quite opposite co-ordinate system why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the people who developed OpenGL thought that their coordinate system (with the origin at the bottom left) was better for 3D applications and the people who developed UIKit thought that their coordinate system (origin at top left) was the better choice for the kind of apps that UIKit supports.

And arguably, both teams made the right choice.